# Asp.net linkbuttons not firing their click events on disabling javascript?

Tags: asp.net-4.5

I am facing a peculiar problem in asp.net. I have a link button with following specifications.
Linkbutton-

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click" OnClientClick="control_visible('Calendar1', 'Calendar2', 'visible')" ClientIDMode="Static">
```

OnClientClick() js function-

```
function control_visible(control1id,control2id, control1visibility)     //toggles visibility b/w two controls with opp visibility
{
    document.getElementById(control1id).style.visibility = control1visibility;

    if (control1visibility == "visible")
    {
        document.getElementById(control2id).style.visibility = "collapse";
    }
    else        
    {
        document.getElementById(control2id).style.visibility = "visible";
    }

    return false;
}
```

The code inside linkbutton is irrevelant in regard of the problem i am facing.
What seems logical is when you disable the js on your browser, then your code behind should execute normally.
But in above case as i disable the js, my linkbutton stops interacting with the server & don't execute its code & i am not even using "return" keyword in *OnClientClick* function call of linkbutton, which could possibly prevent the code from running, if it provides a "false" in the *onclientclick* function call when the js is disabled.
I don't understand...is this for a fact that upon calling a js function with js disabled, even the code-behind fails to execute or i am possibly missing something??
Thanks, i hope i made it clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use button if you want to execute events with js disabled

```
<asp:Button runat="server" />
```

LinkButton(s) got translated into something like

```
<a href="javascript:something_like_invoke_postback()" onclick="your_on_client_click" />
```

so once you disable javascript, they're dead. OnClientClick handler is irelevant for this problem (it won't fire event if it is empty with js disabled).

Comment: Thanks for quick reply Ondrej. You gotta admit that's an important but relatively lesser known fact. But i gotta use linkbutton for this purpose as i want to LINKIFY the div within it & I can't do that with a button. So..any suggestions??

Comment: Yes - but you're not going to like it. Either switch to MVC or use classical hyperlink (asp:HyperLink if you want to have server control).

Comment: asp hyperlink does not have any click event & i don't know MVC. But i figured out that asp imagebutton is doing the trick for me as it does not have the side-effects of linkbutton. :))